# Create a Clould look a like tags search

Tags: html, css

Right now im trying to create a view like this (check image).

[image]

To ve honest, i cant even find the name to look something similar to this, already try with "cloud tags search view html css" with that keywords, but cant find something, a guide will be great

**note** Onlye need the "right view" the part where the keyword tags are showed

Comment: Are you asking about the client side or server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags in the right had view are generated from the server against a tag database, free text search or some other source medium. Typically when tags are displayed in a cloud they are 'weighted' against a metric ie. most frequently searched, applicable posts \ pages or any other weighting metric. Then these tags are generated using css classes to determine the sizing in the cloud.

For example your highest searching tag (or highest grossing) usually gets larger text sizes, colors and font weights. Whereas the lower grossing tags appear smaller, different shades and lower font weights.

Although not exactly a reputed source I came across this result:

http://opencloud.mcavallo.org/samples/index.jsp

Searched by our favorite search engine with the term **html tag cloud css**

Which does as listed above. However it is up to you how to generate the tags, colors and "weightings"